Unable to Fetch Repls or Create New Ones on Replit Web Interface
I'm facing an issue with Replit where I can't fetch my existing Repls or create new ones using the web interface. Whenever I try, I get the following error:
Unable to fetch repls. Please try again.

Here are some additional details:

This issue occurs only on the web version of Replit.
The desktop application works perfectly fine—I can fetch my Repls and create new ones without any issues.
I've tried clearing my browser cache, disabling extensions, and using multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), but the issue persists.
My internet connection is stable, and I'm not using a VPN or proxy.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there a known solution or workaround?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I know Replit tells you to come here for customer service, but these kinds of questions are generally off topic for Stack Overflow. See also: Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

I don’t understand how a platform like Replit.com doesn’t have a proper customer support system, not even through forums.
This is extremely disappointing, and I will no longer use it. I’ll also advise others to avoid using this platform.
